# Inheriting formatting in django template

Tags: django, templates, inheritance

I am trying to pass on some formatting (centering) in my django template.  My base reads:

```
{% block main_content %}{% endblock %}
```

Then I have a sub base file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main_content %}
    <br><br><br>
    <center>
        {% block login_content %}{% endblock %}
    </center>
{% endblock %}
```

And finally my actual content

```
{% extends "subbase.html" %}
{% block login_content %}
    <form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}

          <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}" />
          <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm not seeing the form though in the final template.  I just get a blank screen.  If I change the final {% block login_content %} to {% block main_content %} then I get the form, but not the formatting (which I understand).  I don't understand why I'm getting absolutely nothing when I try to implement formatting this way.

Comment: I assume the template is just an example and you don't use center and br like that IRL :-)

Comment: yes, I'm just using them as a quick and dirty way to see what I want.  Then I'll CSS it up

Comment: what happends if you put {% block login_content %}{% endblock %} outside the main_content block?

Comment: What happens if you remove your *base* file and remove {% extends "base.html" %} from *subbase* file? Does it work properly?

Comment: Possible reason is that you have another *base* template or another *subbase* template with the same name. May be a not correct template is in use. Check it please.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to have wasted your time.  Turns out I was editing the wrong version of the file, so none of my changes were being passed to the correct subbase.html

## fail

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, this might sound obvious, but your inheritance seems perfectly fine... Are you sure you are passing the form as a dict argument to the actual view (try putting the form in a context processor to debug?)

Comment: Yes, the form seems fine.  In fact, if I even delete the form and put in some dummy text, I still don't get any output

Comment: Thats odd, I tried extending an extended template and it parses content fine

Comment: started from scratch due to both your comments and found a very stupid error.